# Asembler - multiplying two big hexadecimal numbers

Tags: assembly, multiplication

I have task to do for my lab, in input user types two big hexadecimal numbers for ex. CF00A1, FF112B and output is result of multiplication of those.
Im struggling with this task, and I have few questions:
Should I convert ASCII to binary or decimal to make further
calculations?
Secondly - it is said in this task that I should use multiplication
algorithms for this task for ex. by parts
Could someone share me code or some useful tips because Its my first adventure with asembly language.
edit:
architecture x86, preferable AT&T syntax, and hexadecimal numbers can contain max 200 characters.

Comment: What architecture are you programming for?  How large are the hexadecimal numbers supposed to be?

Comment: Ah yeah, I should have mentioned that - architecture x86, preferable AT&T syntax, and hexadecimal numbers can contain max 200 characters.

Comment: This is a general problem known variously as "multiple-precision arithmetic" or  "multiprecision arithmetic". The solution is too broad to fit into the SO Q&A format, but you can look up the term to learn how it works. (Also, you don't have to use assembly language to implement multiprecision arithmetic.)

Comment: @kkkkkkkkkk As a first step, try to convert the hexadecimal numbers into arrays of bytes or dwords.  Then, implement a multi-precision multiplication algorithm.  The simplest one is long multiplication which you might remember from elementary school.  Try to give it a try, but watch out for overflow issues.